# Add column in table by merging object attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4oDjkPN0GJpB5H94ww56?p=preview) I made. Whats the best approach to merge `$scope.blacklist`into `$scope.friends` when `ng-click="showColumn('Blacklist');"` is fired, finally a new column called `Coming` need to be added to the table.

### ng-app & ng-controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', MainCtrl]);

function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                      {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                      {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                      {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                      {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'}];

    $scope.coming = [{coming: 'x'},
                      {coming: 'x'},
                      {coming: 'x'},
                      {coming: 'x'},
                      {coming: 'x'}];

    $scope.showColumn = function (type) {
      if (type === 'coming') {
        // INSERT Code here
        console.log('Try add column coming');
      }
    } 

    $scope.getFilter = function () {
        return $scope.filter;
    };  

    $scope.setFilter = function (filter) {
        $scope.filter = filter;
    }; 
}
```

### View

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <hr />
        <a ng-click="showColumn('coming');">Show "coming"</a>
        <hr />
        <table class="table">
          <tbody> 
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:getFilter()">
              <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
              <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Forked your plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PYebozlkU4dFfqsL4Ohk?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', MainCtrl]);

function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {

  $scope.friends = [{
    name: 'John',
    phone: '555-1276'
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
  }, {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '555-4321'
  }, {
    name: 'Adam',
    phone: '555-5678'
  }, {
    name: 'Julie',
    phone: '555-8765'
  }];

  $scope.coming = [{
    coming: 'x'
  }, {
    coming: 'x'
  }, {
    coming: 'x'
  }, {
    coming: 'x'
  }, {
    coming: 'x'
  }];

  $scope.showColumn = function(type) {
    if (type === 'coming') {
      $scope.showComing = true;
      angular.forEach($scope.friends, function(obj, i) {
        obj.coming = ($scope.coming[i] || {}).coming;
      })
    }
  }

  $scope.getFilter = function() {
    return $scope.filter;
  };

  $scope.setFilter = function(filter) {
    $scope.filter = filter;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <hr />
    <a ng-click="showColumn('coming');">Show "coming"</a>
    <hr />
    <table class="table">
      <tbody> 
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th ng-show="showComing">Coming</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:getFilter()">
          <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
          <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
          <td ng-show="showComing">{{friend.coming}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```